# Symfony2 override User.orm.xml

Tags: php, xml, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I need to override this Symfony\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\model\User.orm.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <mapped-superclass name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">

        <field name="username" column="username" type="string" length="255" />

        <field name="usernameCanonical" column="username_canonical" type="string" length="255" unique="true" />

        <field name="email" column="email" type="string" length="255" />

        <field name="emailCanonical" column="email_canonical" type="string" length="255" unique="true" />

        <field name="enabled" column="enabled" type="boolean" />

        <field name="salt" column="salt" type="string" />

        <field name="password" column="password" type="string" />

        <field name="lastLogin" column="last_login" type="datetime" nullable="true" />

        <field name="locked" column="locked" type="boolean" />

        <field name="expired" column="expired" type="boolean" />

        <field name="expiresAt" column="expires_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />

        <field name="confirmationToken" column="confirmation_token" type="string" nullable="true" />

        <field name="passwordRequestedAt" column="password_requested_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />

        <field name="roles" column="roles" type="array" />

        <field name="credentialsExpired" column="credentials_expired" type="boolean" />

        <field name="credentialsExpireAt" column="credentials_expire_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />

    </mapped-superclass>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

I need to change this field:

```
<field name="email" column="email" type="string" length="255" />
```

To this:

```
<field name="email" column="email_address" type="string" length="255" />
```

I add getParent method to my UserBundle. I have copied Symfony\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\model\User.orm.xml 
to my 
Bundle Symfony\src\Acme\UserBundle\Resources\doctrine\model\User.orm.xml 
but when I changed it I do not see the effect. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have figured out. The solution is to add special annotation to User entity which I create earlier form FOSUserBundle documentation.

```
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email_address", length=255)),
 * })
```

The whole class should look like:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf_guard_user")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email_address", length=255)),
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Comment: How to delete a column from the mapping ? When I do so, i get the error "invalid mapping file"

Comment: Sorry for late response. This answer has 2 years I do not remember now, but probably it is not possible to do it with annotation. Sorry I do not have opportunity to check it but annotation says override not remove. If you are working in commercial project I would not recommend AttributeOverride as solution for using integration with FOSUserBundle, it is better to write it by yourself then use it as we did in my project.